# Добавление метки в wp, без использования админ панели

Tags: wordpress

Необходимо добавить метку в wp без использования админ-панели. Пробовал добавлять запись в таблицу wp_terms, но в админке данную метку не видно, видимо, её ещё где-то необходимо прописать/связать...

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию `wp_insert_category` с указанием таксономии `post_tag`:

```
wp_insert_category( array(
    'cat_name' => 'Имя метки',
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag'
) );
```

Comment: спс за подсказку, но данный метод мне не подходит( не подскажите, можно ли обойтись добавление метки с помощью записей в бд?

Comment: `wp_insert_category` использует для добавления записи в БД функцию `wp_insert_term`, смотрите ее, тут описание и исходный код: http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_insert_term Сейчас не могу проверить, но нужно обновлять таблицы `terms` и `term_taxonomy`.